# Adding JSON files to Qt project

Tags: qt

I want to add JSON schema files to my Qt project so that I can read from them during runtime. Those files are part of an npm package and there can be multiple versions in the future. For example the directory structure could look like this:

```
node_modules  
|
└───version-0.0.1
│   │
│   └───schema.json
│   
└───version-0.0.2
    |
    └───schema.json
...
```

I basically want to be able to include that entire 'node_modules' directory as a resource in my Qt project (be part of the executable file) so that I can parse through the directories and use the schema I want at runtime. And in the future when the directory is updated to include more schemas, I want those to be automatically included as well. How can I achieve this? Can I include the 'node_modules' directory as a resource?

Comment: The short answer to `Can I include the 'node_modules' directory as a resource? ` is probably 'yes'.  Please see the [associated documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html).

Comment: Moreover if you want this schema files to be a part of an executable file, you must include them as resources

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I could just add `node_modules` to the `RESOURCES` property in my .pro file and Qt would automatically generate a qrc file and add all files in the node_modules directory into the resources folder of the application. I could then simply access all the files in the directory using the path ":node_modules/..."